# How can I Execute a Python Crawler on my own Server

Tags: python, web-crawler, executable, server

I have created a Crawler in Python.

I would like to execute the Crawler hourly on my server(shared hosting).
The crawler generates excel files and these would have to be saved on my server.

How can I do this?

Thanks allot in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a linux box, you can set up a cron job to run it as often as you'd like.

See http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html for more details.